# FileNotFoundError and [Errno 2] or Unicodeescape or No permission errors for opening an excel file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to start my first data science project following a youtube guide. However, I can not get Jupyter to open the file with data on it.

```
%pylab inline
import pandas 
import seaborn
import os.path
testFile = open("uber-raw-data-arp14")
print(testFile)
```

result in:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-6ce8a207c16e> in <module>
      3 import seaborn
      4 import os.path
----> 5 testFile = open("uber-raw-data-arp14")
      6 print(testFile)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'uber-raw-data-arp14'
```

And when I try:

```
%pylab inline
import pandas 
import seaborn
import os

os.startfile("C:\Users\caleb\PythonData\uber-raw-data-apr14")
```

The result is:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

I ended up trying a million other ways from google today and another error I got was "You don't have permission".

I am not sure if I am using anaconda3 prompt instead of cmd is effecting that, but if it is, my cmd has kernal errors when I open jupyter notebook through it.

So I can not use jupyter notebook unless its through the anaconda3 prompt.

Comment: unicode error is because of forward slash. use backslash or double forward slash

Comment: So I was able to open the folder "PythonData" by using backslash, but I still cannot open the excel doccument. when I put: df = pandas.read_excel (r'C:/Users/caleb/PythonData/uber-raw-data-apr14.xlsx') it just says file not found.

Comment: Can you run command line, type: cd C:/Users/caleb/PythonData/uber-raw-data-apr14.xlsx. Does it open the excel?

Comment: I figured it out actually I just put ' data = (r'C:/Users/caleb/PythonData/uber-raw-data-apr14.csv') ' and then pandas.read_csv(data). Thank you for the help!

Comment: Commenters here seem to be confused between forward slash (/) and backslash (\).  Nitpicky, but important to use the right terminology.